# Ошибка в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

При установке visual studio наткнулся на такое вот сообщение: The package cache path cannot overlap with shared installation path. Как это все дело исправить, чтобы установилась ide?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/install/disable-or-move-the-package-cache?view=vs-2019

Comment: к сожалению не помогло...